# Deploying source to web server with deleting not needed files

Tags: web-deployment, filezilla

When developing for asp.net using visual studio for web, it is really convenient that when you deploy your website to the web server, it will cleverly check which files have been changed and only upload those files. In addition, if you deleted some files from your source, it detects that too and deletes those files from the web server since they are no longer needed.

I started developing with the LAMP stack and am wondering how you can deploy to a web server in a similar way.

I tried using Filezilla and on copy/pasting the source files to the web server, you have these options if there are similar files:

-Overwrite
-Overwrite if source is newer
-Overwrite if different size
-Overwrite if different size or source newer

"Overwrite if source is newer" works, kind of, but it only checks the date modified, not the content of the file. Also, the above method does not delete files from the web server that were deleted from the source.

Is there a better way to do this with Filezilla? (or maybe use some other program?)

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using rsync?

Comment: I've never heard of rsync... is this the thing to use?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am on a windows machine. I just need a simple way to push new files to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps) to accomplish this.

When you want to push out changes you would do something like this form your production server.

```
rysnc -av user@<developmentIp>:/web/root/* /production/web/root/
```

The pattern is `rsync --flags [user@host:]/source/dir [user@host:]/destination/dir`

You only need the user@host stuff for remote hosts. The user must have ssh access to the host.

Couple little suggestions.

- The command can be run from the source or destination. I find it better to run the command from the destination, for permissions issues (i.e. your reading from the remote and writing to the local)
- Do some tests first, I always mix up the directory stuff; do I need the end slash, should I use the star, ...
- Read the man page, there are alot of available options that may be helpful (`--delete`, `--exclude`, `-a`)

Comment: Still a little confused. I read up on this and am not too sure how to get started. I'm not seeing the part where I enter my web host credentials and ftp over my new website files to the web server.